# How do I solve for number of grams of salt in a tank at time 't' with a changing volume correctly (mixing problem)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I went through this problem by adapting my work from a problem that had a constant volume, but my final answer is not realistic, so I know I messed up somewhere along the road. The question gives this information:

-Tank contains 200 liters of  fluid in which 30 grams of salt is dissolved

-1 gram of salt per liter is pumped into the tank at a rate of 4L/min

-The well-mixed solution is then pumped out at a rate of 5L/min

From  this, found the volume equation $V(t) = 200 - t$.

I let $x(t)$ be the amount of salt in grams dissolved in the tank.

I then set up the differential:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = (1 g/L)(4L/min) - (5 L/min)\frac{x(t)}{200-t}.$$

I set up the equation in linear differential form:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{5x(t)}{200-t} = 4.$$

I let $P(t) = \frac{5}{200-t}$.

So my integrating factor $\mu = e^{-5\ln(200-t)}$, which simplified was $\mu = (200-t)^{-5}$

My new equation is
$x(t)(200-t)^{-5} = -(200-t)^{-4} + C$, which simplified is

$$x(t) = -(200-t)^1 + C(200-t)^5.$$

Using initial value $x(0) = 30$, I found $C = -170/200^5$

My final equation is $x(t) = -(200-t)-(170/200^5)(200-5)^5$.

Testing any number of $t$ values, I can tell this equation is nowhere near giving an accurate amount of salt in the tank, but I'm unsure which part of the problem I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: You did a great job of showing your set-up and your work. Glad to see the serious work in a question here at MSE. Now please work on learning a tiny bit of MathJax for posting beautiful questions!! :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks! I will certainly look into formatting my problems with clean formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the problem up and solved it perfectly except for ...

... a dropped factor of $-1$ on the RHS when you integrated.